# Node List not live/ not transferring to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes, clonenode

I am attempting to invoke a function per node. When the notch array is defined in the notchlick function it doesn't create the array. When I place it outside the functions the array only includes the original nodes and not the clones. Since the array is an htmlcollection I assume it would be a live list.

```
let notch;

poppin = function () {

ole.classList.replace ('okay', 'olay');

ulay.classList.replace ('unlay', 'ulay');

bup[0].classList.replace ('bup', 'cup');

pegs.classList.replace ('pegs', 'legs');

if (!ran) {

    notches();
    switches();
}

count = 0;
}

let notches = function () {

for (a = 0; a < tn; a++) {

    let svgc = svg.cloneNode(true);

    pegs.append(svgc);
}   

ran = true;

}

notch = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('svg'));

notchlick = function (k) {

notch[k].onclick = function () {

    spright();
    spleft();   
    bup[count].classList.replace ('cup' , 'bup');

    count = k;
    bup[count].classList.replace ('bup' , 'cup')        
}
}

switches = function () {

for (k = 0; k < notch.length; k++) {

    notchlick(k);
}
}
```

Cloned nodes don't act how originals do. Is this the source of the issue when the array is declared outside the function as shown? Also given my understanding of closures I'm missing why the array doesn't register when nested in a function.

Comment: Why not add the click handler to the container? `pegs.addEventListener('click',(e)=>e.target.tagName==='SVG'?svgClicked(e):undefined)`

Comment: Can you explain your code. I understand a click event on the container but transferring that to the exact elements which is what I assume the rest of the code does, I'm not grasping that

Comment: Arrow function that uses a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to either execute svgClicked with the event as argument or does nothing (return undefined) if the element clicked is not `<svg`